# Logging sql query parameter values

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, nlog

I use nlog and following setting to log sql queries:

```
<logger name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*" 
        minlevel="Trace" writeTo="sqllogfile" final="true" />
```

It works as expected, but doesn't log parameter values, the queries look like this:

```
2017-07-31 13:49:03.8836|  INFO  |Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InterceptingLogger`1.Log|Executed DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [e].[Id], [e].[AccessFailedCount], [e].[ConcurrencyStamp], [e].[Email], [e].[EmailConfirmed], [e].[HeliosLoginId], [e].[LockoutEnabled], [e].[LockoutEnd], [e].[Name], [e].[NormalizedEmail], [e].[NormalizedUserName], [e].[PasswordHash], [e].[PhoneNumber], [e].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [e].[SecurityStamp], [e].[TwoFactorEnabled], [e].[UserName]
FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [e]
WHERE [e].[Id] = @__get_Item_0
```

Is it possible to show value of the `@__get_Item_0` parameter ?

Thank you

Comment: On your `DbContextOptionsBuilder` call `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` By default EF Core does not log values since values may contain sensitive data.

Comment: @Smit I consider this an answer, feel free to post it again. Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, EF Core hides the data in the SQL which gets logged. Queries can have various data some of which can be sensitive information (like customer's social security number or credit card information). Therefore logs have `?` instead of actual values.

Though at times, developer may want to see the values especially while debugging nasty bugs. To enable logging actual values, you need to configure your dbcontext.

You need to call `EnableSensitiveDataLogging()` on your `DbContextOptionsBuilder`. Since there are multiple ways to configure db context options, easiest way to get hold of it would be where you are configuring your provider with connection string (e.g. `UseSqlServer`) you can chain it right after it.

Example

```
optionsBuilder
    .UseSqlServer("connectionstring")
    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
```

Comment: Is there a similar configuration option for EF6?